# Best way to return a String as a parameter in Java

Tags: java, string, parameter-passing

I frequently encounter a situation where I want to return several values from a Java method, and it's not worth creating a class/object just for that purpose. In my specific current case, I have a number of input-validation methods which compute intermediate results that I'd like to re-use in the callers.

One solution is to pass in a new list and have the method append my results, but that's misleading when I know there will always be a single value for each parameter that I want to return.

The most common such situation is when I want to return a string. I can pass in a StringBuilder or StringBuffer, and have the method fill in the value. But for some strange reason these classes do not provide a set() method (other than the constructor, which is not helpful for this purpose). The closest I can come up with is `myStringBuilder.replace(0, myStringBuilder.length(), myString)`, but that's really ugly and does not communicate my intent clearly. So I would like to extend these classes with a utility class of my own, which adds a set() method (and internally uses replace), but these classes are declared `final` for some bizarre reason, and I can't do that either.

Am I missing something? Is there some preferred way of doing what I want - passing in some kind of writable string buffer into which the method can put a value? Is there a good reason these classes are declared final?

An example of such a method might be:

```
void foo(List<ObjectA> arg1, List<ObjectB> arg2, StringBuffer somethingInteresting, StringBuffer somethingElseInteresting)
```

I don't want to replace the last two parameters with List if the two strings are unrelated semantically, because I'm imposing some semantics on the list order which is not clearly communicated. I don't want to pass in two separate List and expect each to return with size() of 1, because that again is not clear to the caller.

Comment: can you share the expected method signature?

Comment: Hopefully the current text is clearer then. I meant for any given parameter I expect a single result, so passing in a bunch of lists, each of which is expected to have a size() of 1 upon return, is misleading.

Comment: I have added a method signature and some additional clarifying text.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear and is sort of a wall-of-text. Can you add a concise statement of what exactly you're trying to accomplish, in the actual context of your program?

Comment: The technical term for what you're describing is an *out parameter*. Java has no direct support for this feature.

Comment: Right. And StringBuffers and StringBuilders are not designed for this purpose.

Comment: By the way, if you care to post a more detailed version of your code (maybe in a gist or on the code review stack overflow) I would enjoy helping you find a good way to refactor it to gain the reuse you are after.

Comment: @Bill K: That's very generous. Unfortunately the code is proprietary, and the signatures, objects, and context are sufficiently complex that attempting to publish a redacted code segment is onerous. Thanks anyway, I do appreciate the offer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your resistance to creating another class.  I'm not saying your question is invalid, but if you want to return a bunch of values and your function is aware of the Single Responsibility Principle, then those values are related.  Since they are related, you will have other things that want to operate on them as a group.  These operations belong in the class you return.

I've never regretted creating a class to return similar values.

I've never regretted splitting up a class that returned two unrelated values.

Java tries not to make it easy to do things you will regret.

By the way, to answer the question directly, You might return an array of strings.  Return value of String[] and have it return something like "new String[] {firstString, secondString, thirdString}", but as I said this is the wrong path to take in general.

You COULD create a mutable string as you say, but there is a very good reason they are immutable. Immutability is the key to thread safety--even if you don't think you are using threads much, having values change underneath you is a problem.  Languages that are highly threaded are shifting towards immutability (functional style)--I wouldn't start building an infrastructure going away from it.

Comment: Thanks. Semantically I don't think passing in an array is much different than passing in a List (although it's lighter-weight) - in both cases the semantic ordering of results is implicit, which is bad.

Comment: Yes, passing an array or a list is bad, as I said, create a class--preferably an immutable one.  I was just trying to answer the question asked.

Comment: Also, please don't mutate the things passed into you unless it really needs to be done.  It's unexpected behavior that the next editor will easily miss.  You really should return your results in the return value.  Java doesn't have "out" parameters for a reason--they are just a bad idea.  Mutating a business object with state in some predictable way is reasonable though.

Comment: BTW - "SRP"? I don't recognize that acronym.

Comment: @BobDoolittle ps--sorry, I wasn't trying to be elite or anything, I just didn't want to figure out if I could spell responsibility correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like using `myStringBuilder.replace(0, myStringBuilder.length(), myString)` because its intent is unclear, you can use

```
  myStringBuilder.setLength(0);     // clears the existing content
  myStringBuilder.append(myString); // sets the new string
```

Comment: I guess I am just mystified as to why the class didn't provide a method to do this in the first place. Seems like a big oversight. Maybe (as Bill K suggested) this is intentional, and designed to steer people away from simulating return parameters with them :-)

Comment: I still see no good reason for declaring these classes 'final', thus preventing anybody from extending them with additional functionality.

Comment: Final is mostly a speed issue.  These objects are used so often that the compiler can make some pretty huge speed gains because they are final.  Remember--Java is about 2x slower than C, that is blazingly fast for a vm-based language that offers garbage collection and has no pointers.  They sped up everything they possibly could to do this.  They could also be providing some level of trust--when a method takes/returns a string you can trust a lot of assumptions, if it wasn't final--who knows?  It could even be mutating on a timer event or something!?!